# The planet was seen "with" or "through" the telescope?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which one of the following is grammatically correct?

1. The planet was seen **through** the telescope.
2. The planet was seen **with** the telescope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically correct.

The second sentence could be taken to mean that the planet and the telescope were seen together. That is absurd in this case, but in other cases could be ambiguous:

> The Captain was seen through the telescope.

means a telescope was used to observe the Captain.

> The Captain was seen with the telescope.

could quite reasonably mean that the Captain was observed to be in possession of the telescope.

Answer (score 2):

Both are completely grammatical, but have different meanings (though in practice the meanings are nearly interchangeable).

"With the telescope" means that the telescope is the tool used. "Through the telescope" means that the telescope is the medium or channel by which the seeing happened.

I can't think of a likely context in which one would apply and not the other, so functionally they are interchangeable; but that's partly because of how a telescope works. I think if you substitute "camera", then "with a camera" is likely, but "through a camera" is distinctly odd to me.

Side note: I don't count questions about choice of prepositions as grammatical at all: grammatically all prepositions are interchangeable. Semantically, of course some don't make sense; and idiomatically, some combinations just aren't used. But I wouldn't call the distinction 'grammatical' .

Answer (score 0):

> The planet was seen _____ the telescope.

Both are grammatical.

As is  *any* English preposition used in that blank. Here are about 60  that are grammatical in that sentence; most of them also make sense:

aboard
about
above
across
after
against
along
amid
among
around
as
at
before
behind
below
beneath
beside
besides
between
beyond
but
by
despite
down
during
except
excepting
excluding
following
for
from
in
inside
into
like
minus
near
of
off
on
onto
opposite
outside
over
past
regarding
round
save
since
through
to
toward
towards
under
underneath
unlike
until
up
upon
versus
via
with
within
without

Some of them (eg, *amid*,  *among* and a couple others)   might not make sense, but that's a different story.